# How to get YUV from the decode output of MediaCodec and draw it on GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, yuv, glsurfaceview

I'm need to play a video stream using GLSurfaceView. And I tried to get the outputs and render them. But the color is not correct.

I dump the outputbuffer to file and open it with yuv viewer, the color is not correct too. So I doubt that I use the wrong way to get the outputbuffer? Here's the code:

```
mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 500000);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, 0);
mediaCodec.start();

ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();

int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
   ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
   inputBuffer.clear();
   inputBuffer.put(avFrame.frmData);
   mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, avFrame.frmData.length, 0L, 0);
  }

MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
    ByteBuffer outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];

    outputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
    outputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);
    outputBuffer.get(outData);

    mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, true);
    outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
    mRenderer.setFrame(outData, avFrame.getVideoWidth(), avFrame.getVideoHeight());
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify the data in some way? If all you want to do is play the video frames, you can just send them directly to the Surface. See Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) for various examples. If you do need the raw YUV, understand that the KEY_COLOR_FORMAT is ignored by the decoder -- the decoder gets to use whatever format it wants. Additional info on http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ .

Comment: Thanks, fadden. Now I know that the format of  the output YUV is related to the SoC. I decide to use SurfaceView instead.